# Custom post type and standard post not displaying or working

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-type

I want to display 5 images of custom post type 'project' and 1 standard post in the front-page. I have tried to merge both queries in one, however its not working.

FYI: I have set the theme support for thumbnail.

This is what I have so far on my front-page, but its not displaying them:

```
<div class="content lg-grid">
    <?php

    $query1 = new WP_Query(array(
        'project' => array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_type' => 'project'
        )
    ));
    $query2 = new WP_Query(array(
        'post' => array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'category' => 'art'
        )
    ));
    $result = new WP_Query();
    $result->posts = array_merge($query1->posts, $query2->posts);

    while ($result->have_posts()) : $result->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="project-item">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" />
                    <h5 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                </a>
            </div>

    <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query args contains a nested array, so it won't work that way — the items like `posts_per_page` belongs in the main array (e.g. `new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) )`). So it should be like this:

Note that the `'category' => 'art'` won't work. Instead, use the `category_name` parameter to query posts by the category *slug*.

```php
$query1 = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type'      => 'project',
) );
$query2 = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category_name'  => 'art',
) );
$posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );
```

Secondly, you don't need the third `WP_Query` instance (i.e. `$result`). Instead, you could use a `foreach` loop in place of `while`, then use [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) to setup the global post variable (`$post`) so that functions like `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` would work as expected.

And note that [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) doesn't return the post thumbnail's URL; instead, it displays the post thumbnail, i.e. `echo` an `<img>` tag, hence you can't use the function in the image's `src` attribute.

```php
foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="project-item">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h5 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;
```

Now that should work.

---

But I don't think it's necessary to merge the posts, and I would likely use a [template part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) for querying and displaying the standard post, and then load the template part from the `front-page.php` template:

- `front-page.php`

  ```php
  <?php
  // Query 5 "project" posts.
  $projects = new WP_Query( [
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'post_type'      => 'project',
  ] );

  $i = 0; // post counter
  while ( $projects->have_posts() ) : $projects->the_post();
      // Displays the default post before the first "project".
      if ( 0 === $i ) {
          get_template_part( 'my-template-part' ); // no .php
      }
  ?>
      your code
  <?php
      $i++;
  endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  ```
- `my-template-part.php`:

  ```php
  <?php
  // Query 1 standard post.
  $art_posts = new WP_Query( [
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'category_name'  => 'art',
  ] );

  while ( $art_posts->have_posts() ) : $art_posts->the_post();
  ?>
      your code
  <?php
  endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sally. Much appreciated.

Comment: Where you have added the if statement for get_template_part in the front-page, can I just add the $art_posts query in there?

Comment: Yes, you can, if you want to, but I thought it's neater to have the code in a template part. And see the `if ( 0 === $i )` - that's where the template part is called, before the first `project` post is displayed.

Comment: You are right, a template is most neater that way. I just thought I would ask to see if it was possible just for learning purposes. Thanks again, Sally ;)